# Angular Universal - timeout should not be used

Tags: angular, angular-universal

so I have been trying to convert my application into angular universal, and for the most part it has been fine.
But I read some "gotchas" earlier: https://github.com/onespeed-articles/angular-universal-gotchas

It suggests that I should not be using `timeout` which is annoying, because in **angularjs** you used it to make things fire after a view was rendered so you could be sure that dimensions of elements were correct, etc.

I have also read that it still persists in **angular 6** so I have this directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, AfterViewInit, Input, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[pyb-button-group]'
})
export class ButtonGroupDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() className: string;

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize() {
    let resize = this.resize;
    let element = this.element;
    let className = this.className;

    setTimeout(function () {
      resize(element, className);
    }, 500);
  }

  constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.resize(this.element, this.className);
  }

  resize(nativeElement, className) {
    let elements = nativeElement.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName(className || 'btn-choice');
    let headerHeight = 0;

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      let element = elements[i];
      let header = element.getElementsByClassName('header');

      if (!header.length) return;

      header = header[0];
      header.style.height = 'auto'; // Reset when resizing the window

      let height = header.offsetHeight;
      if (height > headerHeight) headerHeight = height;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      let element = elements[i];
      let header = element.getElementsByClassName('header');

      if (!header.length) return;

      header = header[0];
      header.style.height = headerHeight + 'px';
    }
  }
}
```

When the browser resizes, it waits for .5 of a second before it tries to resize the button group.
If this is bad practice, what should I use instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When the browser resizes, it waits for .5 of a second before it tries to resize the button group. If this is bad practice, what should I use instead?

You are delaying **every** resize event. Generally, you want to debounce and handle only one event every 500ms. This can be done using an observable, but make sure to unsubscribe when the component is destroyed.

```
observableFromEvent(window, 'resize')
  .pipe(debounceTime(500))
  .subscribe(() => this.resize(this.element, this.className))
```

Also `@HostListener()` never fires events during server-side rendering. There is no DOM on the server to trigger window resize events.

```
  setTimeout(function () {
      resize(element, className);
  }, 500);
```

The `setTimeout` global function that you are using here has a different function signature in NodeJS. When you run the application in Angular Universe it runs inside NodeJS to generate the HTML before it goes to the web browser. setTimeout returns a number on web browsers but returns a resource handle in NodeJS.

If you're going to run your application in Angular Universal then it means you're writing source code that is decoupled from the web browser. That means no direct manipulation of the DOM, no global variables and no global *window* variable.

Comment: I appreciate your answer and I will certainly try to implement what you have suggested. I do have one question about `@HostLinster()` though. I didn't realise it doesn't fire during ssr. Is there something I should be using instead?

Comment: @r3plica you can use `@HostListener` and all of the other Angular features. Keep in mind that Angular Universal just pre-renders the HTML on the server using the compiled bundle of your web application. It then sends that HTML to the web browser and Angular does "hydration" to match the current Angular state with the HTML that has already be rendered.

Answer (score 8):

You want that code to run in browser not in server. The link you provided gives you the solution:

```
 if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
      //your setTimeout here
  }
```