# Angular Universal - settimeout

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I understand that `Settimeout` won't work with angular universal but is there an alternate?

```
typingCallback(that, text, a, direction) {
    if (text.length > 0) {
      let total_length = text.length;
      let current_length = that.typewriter_display.length;
      if (direction == "forward") {
        if (current_length < total_length) {
          that.typewriter_display += text[current_length];
          setTimeout(that.typingCallback, 200, that, text, a, "forward");
        } else {
          //Trigger Remove

          setTimeout(that.typingCallback, 500, that, text, a, "backward");
        }
      } else {
        //Remove 
        if (current_length >= total_length && current_length != 1) {
          var pos = text.lastIndexOf(text[current_length-1]);
          text = text.substring(0,pos) + '' + text.substring(pos+1)
          that.typewriter_display = text;
          setTimeout(that.typingCallback,50,that,text,a,"backward");
        } else {
          //Text Removed send forward
          that.typewriter_display = "";
          if (a < (that.dataText.length-1)) {
            a++;
            setTimeout(function() {
              that.typingCallback(that, that.dataText[a], a,"forward");
            },300)
          } else {
            a = 0;
            setTimeout(function() {
              that.typingCallback(that, that.dataText[a], a,"forward"); 
            }, 200)
          }
        }
      }
    }
    }
```

The above function display's a given text and then removes it before writing another one. I was wondering if there is an alternate to setTimeout so that I can still have the above feature in my website.

Comment: Maybe this helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53787940/angular-universal-timeout-should-not-be-used

Comment: SetTimeout does work with angular universal, it's just that it will slow down rendering. When is that function called?

Comment: It’s a custom function

Answer (score 0):

As far I know there is no alternate for this. setTimeout is window object. So, when you want to use Angular Universal, you need to wrap setTimeout function with isPlatformBrowser.

```
constructor(
@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {}
if(isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
  setTimeout(()=>{
    const dismissRefundModal= document.getElementById('dismissRefundModal');
    dismissRefundModal.click();
  },1500);
}
```